# Purpose of defining parameters in Access query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a query that I was trying to convert to an SQL Server View. It had parameters defined at the top like this:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frmMain]![Date] DateTime, [Forms]![frmMain]![Date2] DateTime;
select * from submissions where date>=[Forms]![frmMain]![Date] and <=[frmMain]![Date2]
```

Now with the linked table `submissions` with SQL Server I was getting 0 results whereas with an unlinked table `submissions` with the same start and end date I was getting the same results.

Both linked and unlinked table had the same data. I just had 2 Access frontends - one with linked and one with unlinked table.

Only when I remove the parameters line from the query do I get the same result. I mean the query needs to be this in linked tables database:

`select * from submissions where date>=[Forms]![frmMain]![Date] and <=[frmMain]![Date2]`

I have been trying to think why this is the case but I cannot think of any reason. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can explain this Access behavior.

Comment: Check linked table column data types https://stackoverflow.com/a/46332580/9439330

Comment: Your SQL has several errors, neither query would run as posted in your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Purpose of defining parameters in Access query

is to free Access from guessing the data type.

If not defined, in some more complex queries, Access may have to give up and you will meet the message: *The query is too complex*.

Comment: What indicates `Date`Field to be linked as string not datetime, as datetime parameters don't work, but variant ones do.